# What are the benefits/drawbacks of a language providing default hashing and equality methods?

Tags: java, python, hash

Languages such as Python and Java provide default hashing and equality implementations based on the identifier of the object. This allows any new class type to be used in hash-based data structures like sets.

In my experience, this is a trap. Developers write their object and then encounter odd (but technically correct) behavior, for example:

```
>>> len(set([Foo(5), Foo(5)]))
2
```

What's the rationale behind this default behavior? When is identity-based hashing and equality useful? What are the benefits of this over just throwing an unimplemented exception to force the programmer to create the behavior that makes sense for this object?

Comment: I think it's ok when it comes to `equals`.  But I 100% agree with you about the hash code.  Personally, I feel that, in Java anyways, `hashCode` should not have been part of the `Object` class altogether.  It should have been defined in some interface that classes would then have been forced to implement if they wanted to be used in some hash table.

Comment: It rather depends on what you expect it to do.  If you expect it use the identity of the object by default, it is not surprising.  There is plenty of data types where identity makes sense, in fact Java has an IdentityHashMap which ignores the hashCode and uses identity anyway.

Comment: equals uses identity by default, and hashCode is designed to reflect how equals is implemented.

Comment: @sstan I agree. Design error. `compareTo(.)` has an interface (`Comparable`). 'Interface bloat' is such a prevalent problem particularly in single inheritance models that I think we should consider any unnecessary members of the super of all classes a negative contribution. While we're at it can we agree making all objects monitors  was also over engineering? In fact if we could go back (and we can't) surely `getClass()` (and not even `finalize()`) should be the only methods in java.lang.Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, we can only speculate as to why the methods were designed that way.  And like many languages, sometimes the designers wish they could go back and change how they designed a certain feature.

For instance, some would argue that if Java were redesigned from scratch, maybe things like [checked exceptions](http://www.mindview.net/Etc/Discussions/CheckedExceptions) would not be included.  Or maybe, the Object class would not include the `wait`, `notify` methods, etc.  So, is it possible that, at least when it comes to the `Object.hashCode()` method, that the feature would be designed differently if Java were redesigned from scratch today?

When it comes to the `equals` method.  I think it makes perfect sense for every object to have it, and for its default implementation to perform reference equality.

As for the `hashCode` method, then I have to agree with OP that, way too often, it's awkward to work with.  Sometimes there are objects which we never want to use in a hash table, but we want to redefine the logic for equality.  So, either you redefine `hashCode` (wasted effort) just to make sure no one accidentally uses it improperly in a hash table later on, or you don't do it, and then you have nasty surprises down the road when someone decides to stick the object in a hash table.

Personally, I found this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) by Eric Lippert, a developer on the C# compiler team, to be very enlightening, and the discussion is very much applicable to Java as well.  In particular, he says the following (the last paragraph is interesting):

> **What is GetHashCode used for?**
>
> It is by design useful for only one thing: putting an object in a hash table. Hence the name.
>
> **Why do we have this method on Object in the first place?**
>
> It makes perfect sense that every object in the type system should provide a GetType method; data's ability to describe itself is a key feature of the CLR type system. And it makes sense that every object should have a ToString, so that it is able to print out a representation of itself as a string, for debugging purposes. It seems plausible that objects should be able to compare themselves to other objects for equality. But why should it be the case that every object should be able to hash itself for insertion into a hash table? Seems like an odd thing to require every object to be able to do.
>
> I think if we were redesigning the type system from scratch today, hashing might be done differently, perhaps with an IHashable interface. But when the CLR type system was designed there were no generic types and therefore a general-purpose hash table needed to be able to store any object.

Answer (score 1):

You answered yourself:

> This allows any new class type to be used in hash-based data structures like sets.

For what concerns the default implementation of these methods:

the default is to use object identifier, because there is no other reasonable default. If the default it's not good, you have to override it. **Only you know the details about your class**.

There may be other situations where different behavior is expected (imagine a class `Person(age)`):

```
len(set([Person(30), Person(45), Person(30)]))
```

makes perfectly sense for it to be 3.

However that is just a lucky coincidence.

Comment: or even `len(set([Person("Peter"), Person("Peter")]))` +1

Comment: But this gets right to the whole point of my question. If "Only I know the details about my class" then it should be an *error* to hash my class if I have not defined what to do. Right?

What reason do they have for using identity instead of saying "I dont know you should probably define this"

Comment: Still the language wants to provide you with a handy default, that is hash() == id(), because that's the only information it knows about the object class. You have to **re-** define it, instead of define it. Personally I like to be less verbose, and that's one of the principles behind OOP.

Comment: @Bachmann Apparently hashing by id is common enough that the designers of the language thought it better to make it the default behavior and risk surprises than to throw an error if it isn't defined. Note that it isn't unreasonable to hash by id. If I go through the trouble to create two instances of an object that compare equal, there's a good chance I still want to consider these as being two, separate things.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this some more and I think I have the answer.

In both Java and Python base objects are not abstract

```
new Object() // Java

object() # Python
```

To do that well its a good idea to implement equals and hashcode and the identity is correct in that case. So the default is more... a consequence of that and inheritance.

My world of throwing an exception would require some sort of model where a base class can define something but force subclasses to implement their own.

Comment: Not accepting this one for now since I wanna see what other people think first

Comment: "Some sort of model where a base class can define something but force subclasses to implement their own". Like an abstract base class?

Comment: Well no. Abstract base class lets you define abstract methods, but if you define them they are not abstract.

So im imagining a world where equals would be defined for objects. But subclasses are forced to make their own. Using the base implementation would be unacceptable.

Not sure if its a good idea, just thinking out loud

Comment: or something like Java 8 interface default methods